# Matlab connect outer boundary points in plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Please find attached a footprint plot of a missile trajectory.
I want to connect the most outer points of the plot, like this: 
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html .
Problem is this boundary function has been implemented in matlab 2014. Unfortunatly, I have to deal with Matlab 2013a...
How can I achieve the same plots as the newer boundary function? My plot-command is simply:

```
plot(x,y)
```

Thanks in advance. 
[image]

edit: I used the convhull command. According to the description it should do the job. However, something is going wrong. the code:

```
figure(4)
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(y_array,x_array,'b*');
k=convhull(y_array,x_array);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-')
```

The same error occcures when using:

```
DT=delaunayTriangulation(y_array',x_array');
[K,v]=convexHull(DT);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(x(K),y(K),'r')
```

[image]

Comment: Why 2 down-votes already...? If I know what is wrong, I can do something about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try using `convhull` on it. From https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html, this is how you can plot the convex hull (if that's what you mean by 'outer points'):

```
xx = -1:.05:1;
yy = abs(sqrt(xx));
[x,y] = pol2cart(xx,yy);
k = convhull(x,y);
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b*')
```

`convhull` was introduced before R2006a, and so should work on your version.

[image: convhull]

Comment: It should do the job, but something is going wrong... please see my edited OP.

Comment: I added an image to show that @akamath's code works as expected. I think in your edited OP your last line should be  `plot(y_array(k),x_array(k),'r-')`, not `plot(x(k),y(k),'r-')`.